# problemas en poder leer archivo de texto en c++

Tags: c

Muy buenas este tengo un problemita y no se si en realidad este leyendo o no el documento le muestro todo paso por paso para que me entiendan que esta pasando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecuto el codigo con normalidad y todo elijo la primera opcion que es para que leea el archivo y se asigne a una variable despues de esto pongo el nombre del archivo de texto que si esta creado pero no me muestra lo que es el archivo ni nada alguien sabe el porque pasa esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    
    void Leercargarunarchivo();
    void Visualizarmatrizsinordenar();
    void Visualizarmatrizordenada();
    void ListadePalabraPalindromo();
    void Listadeverbos();
    void menu();
    
    char nombre[500];
    string  linea;
    string  texto;
    
    void abrir (){
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n        Escribir el nombre del archivo:";
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cin >> nombre;
        ifstream archivo(nombre);
        while (getline(archivo,linea)){
            texto = texto + linea ;
        }
        cout << texto <<endl;
    }
    
    void Visualizarmatrizsinordenar(){
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n        Matriz de palabras repetidas:";
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        getch();
        }
    
    void Visualizarmatrizordenada(){
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n    Matriz de palabras repetidas en orden:";
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        getch();
        }
    
    void ListadePalabraPalindromo(){
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n        Lista de palabras palindromo:";
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        getch();
        }
    
    void Listadeverbos(){
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n               lista de verbos:";
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        getch();
    
        }
    
    int main(){
        int op;
        char nombre[500];
        string  linea;
        string  texto;
        do
        {
            menu();
            cin>> op;
                switch(op)
                {
                    case 1://este es el que se encarga de leer el
                        system ("cls");
                        abrir();
                        system ("pause");
                        break;
                    case 2://este case permitira ver el submeno
                        system ("cls");
                        Visualizarmatrizsinordenar();
                        system ("pause");
                        break;
                    case 3://este case permitira ingresarle stock
                        system ("cls");
                        Visualizarmatrizordenada();
                        system ("pause");
                        break;
                    case 4://este case permitira visualizar la factura
                        system ("cls");
                        ListadePalabraPalindromo();
                        system ("pause");
                        break;
                    case 5://este case permitira salir
                        system ("cls");
                        Listadeverbos();
                        system ("pause");
                        break;
                    case 6://este case permitira salir
                         break;
                }
                system ("cls");
        }while(op !=6);
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n----<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>----";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\n|Gracias vuelva pronto a usar nuestro progras ^w^|";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n----<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>----";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------";
                        system ("pause");
    }//fin main
    
     void menu(){
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n-<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>-";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n||||||||||||||Menu de Opciones||||||||||||||";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n\||| 1. Leer y cargar un archivo         |||";
            cout << "\n\||| 2. Visualizar matriz sin ordenar    |||";
            cout << "\n\||| 3. Visualizar matriz ordenada       |||";
            cout << "\n\||| 4. Lista de Palabra Palindromo      |||" ;
            cout << "\n\||| 5. Lista de verbos                  |||";
            cout << "\n\||| 6. SALIR                            |||";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n-<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>--<( ^.^ )>-";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
            cout << "\nEliga una opcion en orden jerarquica porfavor ^w^:";
            system ("color F5");
     }
```

Comment: El problema que muy seguramente estás teniendo es que **no se está abriendo el archivo** porque **no se encuentra** en el directorio de trabajo. Coge el archivo y haz una copia en la carpeta donde se esté creando el ejecutable y repite el proceso. Ya puestos, no estaría de más que comprobases que el archivo se ha abierto y que no ha dado errores y, de darlos, muestra algún mensaje indicando qué es lo que ha pasado

Comment: @eferion me ayudas con esa partecita please qwp

Comment: Con que? Copiar el archivo donde debería estar? no veo cómo puedo ayudarte con eso. También puedes probar a introducir la ruta absoluta del archivo y ver si así te lo imprime ... es otra opción a tu alcance

Comment: no lo del mensaje de error y pues cree otra carpeta y no me muestra el archivo voy a a ver si con la direccion puedo ya abrirlo @eferion